# Force inherited classes in ASP.NET Core Entity Framework Core to dedicated MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

Having a model `Thread` that should countain all attributes of another model called `Post` I use inheritance:

```
class Post {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    // ...
}
class Thread: Post {
    public int ForumId{get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

EF Core put both in a single table and adds the column `Discriminator`. It contains the name of the class, so that .NET Core can serialize it to the correct type.

My target is:

- Table `Post` with all attributes from the `Post` model
- Table `Thread` with all attributes from models `Thread` and `Post`

#### Why?

1. I'm assuming that both tables will massive grow in the future
2. It blow up my db, since the table definition contains rows from `Thread` that are always empty on `Post` rows
3. From a developer perspective, it simply doesn't look clean and *right*

#### What I already tried

- Creating two different `DbSet<T>` in my `DbContext` for `Post` and `Thread`
- Add `builder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("Post")` in `OnModelCreating` for each entity
- Use `[Table("Post")]` decorator on class definition
- Move shared attributes to a abstract chass and let `Post` and `Thread` inherit from it

#### Some kind of workaround

The last one works:

```
class Content {
    // Shared Attributes like Title
}
class Post: Content {}
class Thread: Content {}
```

But this cause problems when linking the entitys.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is called the TPC, or Table-Per-Concrete Type, relational pattern and is currently unsupported in Entity Framework Core. You can follow the [related issue here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3170).

There is no milestone for this feature at this time, so if you absolutely must do TPC, your only choice is to use EF6 or another alternate ORM that supports this relational strategy, instead of EF Core.

Personally, I would recommend sticking with EF Core and simply using the TPH (Table-Per-Hierarchy) or TPT (Table-Per-Type) relational strategies. The former is actually the default, and will result in a single table for both, with a `Discriminator` column indicating the actual type. The latter is what you get when your use the `ToTable` fluent config or the `[Table]` attribute, and results in a table for the base type holding all the shared properties, and then a table for each derived type, holding only the properties for that type, with a foreign key back to the base type's table. There's a strong relation between something like a post and a thread, and there's value in actually maintaining that relationship at the database level.

Comment: This issue now has the `consider-for-next-release` label as of Nov. 13th, but there hasn't been any significant movement since this answer was posted.